# AWS does not load PHP webpage wherever I try to connect to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, mariadb

I'm new to AWS and I've tried deploying my web application but keep getting `504 Gate-way Timeout`. However, after a bit of debugging and redeploying, I noticed that this was being caused by the PHP segment of my index.php file:

```
<?php
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=<AWS database hostname>; dbname=e-flash-card-schema';
    $username = '<username>';
    $password = '<password>';

    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

    session_start();
    $user = @$_SESSION['Username'];
    $card_number = @$_SESSION['Card_number'];

    $query1 = "SELECT Front_Text FROM `e-flash-card-schema`.`card_text` WHERE Username = '$user' AND Card_Number = '$card_number'";
    $statement1 = $db->prepare($query1);
    $statement1->execute();
    $front_text = $statement1->fetch();
    $statement1->closeCursor();

    $query2 = "SELECT Back_Text FROM `e-flash-card-schema`.`card_text` WHERE Username = '$user' AND Card_Number = '$card_number'";
    $statement2 = $db->prepare($query2);
    $statement2->execute();
    $back_text = $statement2->fetch();
    $statement2->closeCursor();
?>
```

In particular when I removed everything before the `session_start();` line, the webpage was able to load, although it was with errors that I'm assuming were caused by the lines `$query1 = ...` and below. This led me to believe that there's some error caused by my attempt to connect to the database

When I run the same code using XAMPP connecting to the same AWS database server on my machine, everything works fine. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

I'm also using the MariaDB engine for the AWS database and Elastic Beanstalk to deploy my web application if that helps.

Edit: If anyone is looking at this question, could it be because cannot handle this type of thing?

Comment: @KenLee I just tried that but it's still the same outcome

Comment: @KenLee It says connected successfully when I run on my machine, but gives another error in my code: ```Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\E-FlashCard\E-Flash cards project\index.php:26 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\E-FlashCard\E-Flash cards project\index.php on line 26``` I'm guessing because  ```$statement1->execute();``` doesn't work with mysqli?

Comment: @KenLee I switched back to using PDO and it works fine on my machine. ```Connected Succesfully```

Comment: So everything fixed ?

Comment: @KenLee Not really, it always worked fine on my machine, but when I try to deploy to AWS I still get ```504 Gate-way Timeout```

Comment: You need to be looking at the error messages in the server logs. The fact that the browser request is timing out isn't enough debugging information. Also, where is the database the server is trying to connect to? Is it an RDS database?

Comment: @MarkB Yes it's an RDS database. I tried looking them up, but I don't really understand the server logs error messages: ```100.0 % of the requests are erroring with HTTP 4xx. Insufficient request rate (6.0 requests/min) to determine application health.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working by creating a snapshot of the original AWS RDB and configuring my elastic beanstalk database using that snapshot. I then connected to that database instead using the elastic beanstalk database hostname in my PHP code where the original RDB hostname was.

In summary, I wasn't able to connect to the external databse, so I copied that database into my elastic beanstalk configuration and used that instead.

Hope this helps anyone having that might be having the same issue